# How can I use unit tests and TDD to test an app that relies mostly on database CRUD operations?

Tags: java, unit-testing, tdd, jpa

At work, one of my projects is mostly about taking data passed in from an external client and persisting it in a database.  It's a Java enterprise app using JPA and most of our logic revolves around CRUD operations.

The majority of our bugs involve JPA in one way or another.

- Example 1: If you click the save button twice, JPA might try to insert the same entity into the database a second time, causing a primary key violation.
- Example 2: You retrieve an entity from the database, edit it and try to update its data.  JPA may try to create a new instance instead of updating the old one.

Often the solution is needing to add/remove/change a JPA annotation.  Other times it has to do with modifying the DAO logic.

**I can't figure out how to get confidence in our code using unit tests and TDD. I'm not sure if it's because unit tests and TDD are a bad fit, or if I'm approaching the problem wrong.**

Unit tests seem like a bad fit because I can only discover these problems at runtime and I need to deploy to an app server to reproduce the issues.  Usually the database needs to be involved which I consider to be outside the definition of a unit test: These are integration tests.

TDD seems like a bad fit because the deploy + test feedback loop is so slow it makes me very unproductive.  The deploy + test feedback loop takes over 3 minutes, and that's just if I run the tests specifically about the code I'm writing.  To run all the integration tests takes 30+ minutes.

There is code outside this mold and I always unit test that whenever I can.  But the majority of our bugs and the biggest time sinks always involve JPA or the database.

---

[There is another question that is similar](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/174733/is-wrapping-a-third-party-code-the-only-solution-to-unit-test-its-consumers?lq=1), but if I followed the advice I'd be wrapping the most unstable part of my code (the JPA) and testing everything but it. In the context of my question, I'd be in the same bad situation. What's the next step after wrapping the JPA? IMO that question is (perhaps) a step to answer my question, but not an answer to it.

Comment: What you are doing is essentially integration test, as you have to setup the database to actually test. I can imagine that one module would rely on others so make it even more like integration test. I would change the question you have to how to apply TDD approaches to your application.

Comment: @randomA correct, I edited my question to explicitly say that.  I don't understand why you're recommending I change the question.  Can you elaborate?  I want to keep the unit test part in there because I'd *rather* be writing unit tests than integration tests (although I'm aware that `unit testing != TDD`)

Comment: nothing special though, just put TDD there. If you have unit-test there, then many people would think you don't understand thing, etc.. not good for you..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is wrapping a third party code the only solution to unit test its consumers?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/174733/is-wrapping-a-third-party-code-the-only-solution-to-unit-test-its-consumers)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: Unit Testing is not a universal approach for each project. I happen to be in a similar situation at work where a big part of the library I write is interacting with an API. There are very little aspects to unit test in an application where you translate responses, but integration tests are all the more valuable. 

Keep the unit tests for certain things that are easy to isolate. Since the biggest part of your application's logic is interacting with a database you should focus on integration tests.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel OK what about the TDD aspect?  Do I have to drop that?  To me a 3+ minute feedback loop for TDD defeats the benefits.

Comment: Actual TDD (red, green refactor) might be a little much. Once you have the basis of your architecture set up (controllers with some hierarchy, a public API, a few persistance classes) then all you will be doing is add models and test whether they can be saved. I would just write those models and their annotations first and afterwards a test to see if they communicate correctly with the database. You're not really testing for invalid input as you often do in unit testing; you're testing whether parts of your system can communicate correctly with eachother.

Answer (score 7):

One option is to use an in-memory testing database such as [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html); it tends to be about about 10x faster than a standard disk-using database, and with lower startup/teardown times.

Whether it will help does largely depend on whether the JPA issues you are having are general enough that they will still fail on different database. Not much point running tests faster if they miss the bulk of the problems.

But if you can do 10 runs with H2 for every one with the full system, it could pay off.

Comment: That's a nice thought, but I'd still have to deploy to the app server, AFAIK.  That's a lot of the 3+ minutes.  That said, it's definitely worth doing.  But it's still difficult to imagine running the tests as often as I would run unit tests and therefore it seems inefficient to develop using TDD.

Comment: I think there are usually ways around that requirement (e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/toplink/TLADG/testingjpa.htm). Pretty high chance of being more work than justified though; another option would be to get some beefier testing servers and run things in parallel.

Comment: @tieTYT My own proof of concept with hsqldb unit testing a crud web app on github: [TestingWithHsqldb](https://github.com/shagie/TestingWithHsqldb) - the unit tests don't need the app to be deployed.

Answer (score 4):

Other people have answered with "Mock out your DB!" - but what's the point in mocking out your DB layer if you actually need to test how it interacts with your code?

What you're looking for is integration tests and/or automated UI tests. You mentioned that the problem happens when:

```
*If you click the save button twice*
```

The only way to test for this is to write an automated UI test to click on the button twice. Maybe check out Selenium.

You will probably also need a unit testing DB and for your tests point it towards that. A pain to maintain but welcome to TDD in the real world.

Comment: this reads more like a rant than an answer

Comment: I've answered the question three times - integration tests, GUI tests and/or a unit testing DB. Yes it's bit of a rant, I'll edit it to some semblance of sanity now.

Comment: "The only way to test for this is to write an automated UI test to click on the button twice. Maybe check out Selenium." In situations like that, the backend better be preventing that from occurring, otherwise the UI would have direct access to the database.

Answer (score 3):

Databases can be very easy to unit test - you need stored procedures and transactions.

This what Microsoft says about [Database unit testing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833233%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). You can also run unit tests against a database, writing your tests in Java or C# by setting up a DB connection, beginning a transaction, write whatever data you want to use for the test to the DB, run the tests and then rollback. No damage to the DB if you were using one you also deployed to and you get fully isolated tests.

Hope this can give you some insight how to do it within your framework.

Comment: As I said, "The majority of our bugs involve JPA in one way or another.", I think the article's advice would miss all of those.  Also, if you consider those Java/C# tests to still be unit tests, we've got very different definitions.  I think this is good advice in general, but it still seems like it would take a ton of time to deploy and run the suite and therefore not conducive to TDD.  Do you disagree?

Comment: We used to run DB unit tests for our SQL, but then they were all in sprocs. Whilst you can unit test sql directory from other sql procedures, our unit test framework was MSTest so it made sense to run them from there (hey, we got green ticks in the build server which was *the* most important factor). If you have a DB always up (and we did for int. testing anyway) then it is easy to upload all the sql code and run all the unit tests on the build server. Sometimes you just have to be pragmatic about these things.

Comment: I don't think you responded to my first sentence.

Comment: well, just use jpa-unit then. I can't answer how your JPA code works (or doesn't), just try to give you some ideas on getting that sql tested in the db.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you give in your question, you can't unit test/TDD your way into the situation of clicking the button twice to cause an error very easily. But what you can unit test is that in the code which is called when you click the button, if you get an exception from the persistence layer you handle it appropriately (by either mocking out the persistence layer or by using an in-memory database as has been suggested in other answers) - either by rethrowing or displaying an error or whatever.

You're right that TDD can start to break down when you need to perform tests that aren't a good fit for a unit test (i.e. integration/system tests) - this formed quite a lot of the discussion in the recent "Is TDD Dead?" debates between Kent Beck, Martin Fowler and David Heinemeier Hansson: http://martinfowler.com/articles/is-tdd-dead/